# Google MapV2 Marker Positioning

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a Google Android Map V2 with some markers my markers have circles at bottom when i place marker that is being placed on my lat long with icon outer bounds but i want to place icon as the center of my icon circle at the position lat long 
any help [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `anchor()` of MarkerOptions to specify offset of your icon. [See docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#anchor%28float,%20float%29).